# How to make a shortcut of day display e.g Thursday 14/07/2022 => Thu 14/07/2022 in Django html template

Tags: django, django-templates, date-formatting

I have booking start date as follow
`<p>{{ booking.start_time|date:"j/F/Y" }}</p>` on Django html template which it displays the date as  `14/July/2022` on the DOM, how I can make it display like this `Thu 14/07/2022`

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like that:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import datetime
currentdate = datetime.date.today()
print(currentdate)
print(currentdate.strftime("%a %d/%m/%y"))
```

In django html template i think it would be like that. I choose "d" for the day because it will be displayed with leading zeros.

```
<p>{{ booking.start_time|date:"D d/m/Y" }}</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#date):

```
 <p>{{ booking.start_time|date:"D j/m/Y" }}</p>
```